# Error while compiling C program in Sublime 2(Windows)

Tags: c, mingw, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am trying to run c programs in sublime 2, windows machine, I have installed mingw, updated the path variable, and copied the following code in the sublime new build system

```
{
"cmd": ["gcc -o $file_base_name $file && ./$file_base_name"],
"path": "C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin",
"shell": true
```

}

Then i wrote a simple C program

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    printf("ihdfoihsdifhoisdhf");
    return 0;

}
```

On pressing CTRL+SHIFT+b and CTRL+b , i am getting the following error

```
    '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely here:

```
"cmd": ["gcc -o $file_base_name $file && ./$file_base_name"],
```

The dot-slash is current-directory notation for *nix systems, but you're on a Windows system, so try changing that to

```
"cmd": ["gcc -o $file_base_name $file && $file_base_name"],
```

Likewise, you will want to change the forward-slashes `/` in your `path` to backslashes `\`.

Comment: it worked, but i am not able to give input on runtime, i read that sublime doent support it,,what should i do so that the output comes on cmp promt, so that i can give input over there